# call iphone webservice api from an external system

Tags: iphone, web-services, listener

I'm trying to built an app which listens to webservice calls. Is it possible to sent a request to an iphone?

Of course I can implement a service in the app which checks every minute if there is an event, but this would be very uneffective energy management.

Has anyone read something about such problemes and can give me a hint?

Greetings,
matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That where push notifications are for.

Since it's not really possible to keep listening to a socket once your app enters the background. Only VOIP client are allowed to do this.

Comment: ok, I know push notification service, but I thought that sending such messages only works for all users who have the app installed, but I need to inform a specific user.

Is it possible to identify and only display the notification message if the current phone has a specific token like the imei number? Or can I even just send notifications to specific phones?

Comment: Yes it is, you can send the token and some user info to your server and send the notification to only that user. Thats how Twitter, Facebook, Tweetbot,... do it.

Comment: may you know a link explaining this procedure? I already read a lot in the api docs, but did not find anything useful - perhaps I'm blind of all the stuff ;)

Comment: You will need to build that part your self. or use UrbanAirship or some kind of service.